# How to center a Imageview on the screen? (with java code)

Tags: android, imageview

atm i'm using this code, but this code doesn't works for me, because the code is stretching the Image on the screen, i dont want that, i need that the image uses his real size (200x210)

```
        FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(this.getApplicationContext());
        splash = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        splash.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo2);      
        fl.addView(splash);
        fl.setForegroundGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        fl.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        setContentView(fl);
```

How to do it without making a giant image that it is using all the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify scalType if you don't want imageview to stretch your image.

```
splash.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
```

Comment: this will work if i use framelayout? or i have to remove the framelayout?

Answer (score 1):

use this properties of ImageView as shown here:

```
splash.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

and tell me if it is working.